# Samsung's stock Android app in another phone

Tags: stock-android

Okay so here is how it goes. My brother has a Samsung Galaxy j7 and it has some really catchy versions of the normal Android apps like, clock and calculator are very different and good looking though. Now whenever I try to install them in my phone they just crash ( I sent their apks through share-it ) and they don't work.
I just want to ask is there a way I could install them in my phone, maybe edit the check point or copy the code or something else. Am using an Htc, if that helps. I really don't have any programming experience in Android or Java.

Answer (score 0):

Download it off of apk mirror, and it should work. [Here's](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/samsung-electronics-co-ltd/samsung-clock/#description) the link